# UITableViewCells nib showing default values as i scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib, nib

I have created a UITableViewCell nib that I am loading into my tableview, however something weird is happening when I scroll through the table, if I am scrolling down the new cell that comes in shows the default values for a split second and then if I scroll up the same thing is happening at the top.

The code below is deciding which nib to load depending on the data avalible from myObj, hopefully this is understandable

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        // Set cell height
        [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        //call obj array with all of the values from my sorting algorithum
        SearchResultItem *myObj = (searchResultItem*)[dataArrayOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



        // This gets the year string ready  ----->

        // Create Year string
        NSString *yearRangeString = [[NSString alloc] init];

        // do some special stuff here with the years
        if ((myObj.yearStart < 1) && (myObj.yearFinish < 1)){
            //            yearRangeLabel.text = @"";
            yearRangeString = @"";
        }
        if ((myObj.yearStart < 1) && (myObj.yearFinish > 1)){
            //            yearRangeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"upto %i", myObj.yearFinish];
            yearRangeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"upto %i", myObj.yearFinish];
        }
        if ((myObj.yearStart > 1) && (myObj.yearFinish < 1)){
            //            yearRangeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"from %i", myObj.yearStart];
            yearRangeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"from %i", myObj.yearStart];
        }
        if ((myObj.yearStart > 1) && (myObj.yearFinish > 1)){
            //            yearRangeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i to %i",myObj.yearStart, myObj.yearFinish];
            yearRangeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i to %i",myObj.yearStart, myObj.yearFinish];
        }

        // adjust year string is (submodel) is avalible or not
        if (([yearSelectedString isEqualToString:@"all"]) && ([sModelSelectedString isEqualToString:@"all"])) {
            yearRangeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@", myObj.subModel, yearRangeString];
            yearRangeLabel.text = yearRangeString;
        }
        else if ((![yearSelectedString isEqualToString:@"all"]) && ([sModelSelectedString isEqualToString:@"aSearchResultItemll"])) {
            yearRangeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", myObj.subModel];
            yearRangeLabel.text = yearRangeString;
        }
        else if (([yearSelectedString isEqualToString:@"all"]) && (![sModelSelectedString isEqualToString:@"all"])) {
            yearRangeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yearRangeString];
            yearRangeLabel.text = yearRangeString;
        }
        else if ((![yearSelectedString isEqualToString:@"all"]) && (![sModelSelectedString isEqualToString:@"all"])) {
            yearRangeLabel.text = nil;
        }

    // check year string if too large use B nibs ----->

        // Get yearRangeString width to see if you need to use a yearRangeLabel with second line
        CGSize yearStringSize = [yearRangeString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(226, 21) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping ];

        // NSLog(@"width = %f, height = %f", yearStringSize.width, yearStringSize.height);



     // Get rest of nibs ready ----->

        // Set custom cell to display
        // check to see if there is a description, if there is choose the correct tableviewcell

        if (([myObj.note isEqualToString:@""]) && (([sModelSelectedString isEqualToString:@"all"]) || ([yearSelectedString isEqualToString:@"all"])) && (yearStringSize.width <= 100.00)) {

            // Configure the cell using custom cell
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"auSearchCell" owner:self options:nil];

            // Set up the different labels in each cell
            descriptionLabel.text = myObj.sDescription;
            iDLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", myObj.mID];
            cLabel.text = myObj.cDesc;
            INLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", myObj.ssID];

            cell = automativeSearchCell;
        }

        /// other if statments for different types of cells

         //Disclosure Indicator
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a couple of problems. You shouldn't be calling heightForRowAtIndexPath:, it's called by the table view. You should set up any heights you need there based on the index path. It also looks like your dequeuing a normal UITableViewCell every time, and then switching to your other cell if a string is too long. You should do the string size check first, and then dequeue the proper cell. Also, it looks like you're loading the nib every t1me you have the too long string. Instead, you should just register your nib (in viewDidLoad perhaps) and then use the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: method instead of the older method you're using. That method is always guaranteed to dequeue a cell, so there's no need for the if cell == nil clause.

Comment: okay thanks.. looks like I still have abit of work to do then... :(

Comment: the reason I am loading the nib every time is that there is a chance of other nibs being loaded on the same view.. so I have to check for it... there are 4 other if statments I didnt put in because they are pretty much the same.

Comment: @HurkNburkS, are you using static cells? I ask because you said you were seeing values that you have in the nib.

Comment: yup, I have created 6 different static cells I then choose from, there is more to the last if statment in my example code. I know there is a way to programatically code this but this was done at a time when it made alot more sense to me... what I actually think is happening here is the thread gets caught up in the first two if statments too long, thus allowing the xib/nib to be seen without the values set.. as if I am to add those if statments below where I set the last lot of values up this problem dosnt happen. however it needs to be this order so i can figure out the year width

Comment: @HurkNburkS, I don't understand what you're doing then -- if you use static cells, you don't use any of the normal table view data source methods like celForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: when you say static you mean ones that are created in Interface builder right? I have 6 static cells that act as templates. I then will have an array of dictionary values that are used in the labels of each of the templates. The chosen template depends on which dictionary values are used.

Comment: @HurkNburkS, no, you can make both static and dynamic cells in IB. If you select the table view, in the Attributes Inspector at the top, it will either say Dynamic Prototypes or Static Cells. Which do you have?

Comment: okay, sorry for the confusion, my tableview cells each of which have their own view but are of a subclass/view? of the main viewcontroller file are infact dynamic, also my tableview for the main view its self is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your UITableViewCell *cell object is nil (ie, was there anything to dequeue). If so, allocate a new one.

Comment: its weird the new cell is there.. its just showing the default label values that I have in the nib.. instead of loading the values that I have added to it from myObj